# How to delete a div that meets another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to be able to hide a div that meets another in JavaScript.
I found this code but I can't adjust the distance between the red and green div. I need to put a lot of content between the green div and the red div.
In this code the red div disappears when it comes into contact with the green one

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  cacherHeader()
};
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var essai = document.getElementById("essai");
var position_essai = essai.offsetTop;

function cacherHeader() {
  if (window.pageYOffset <= position_essai) {
    if (header.classList.contains("afficher") == false) {
      header.classList.remove("cacher");
      header.classList.add("afficher");
    }
  } else {
    if (header.classList.contains("afficher") == true) {
      header.classList.remove("afficher");
      header.classList.add("cacher");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.fixe {
  position: fixed;
}

.afficher {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 2000ms ease, visibility 2000ms ease;
}

.cacher {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 2000ms ease, visibility 2000ms ease;
}

#header {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

#conteneur_01 {
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#essai {
  background-color: green;
}

#conteneur_02 {
  height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="fixe afficher">header</div>
<div id="conteneur_01">conteneur 1</div>
<div id="essai">Essai</div>
<div id="conteneur_02">conteneur 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you use has nothing to do with "two divs meeting". The `#header` disappears when the `window.pageYOffset` is greater than the `offsetTop` of the `#essai`.

This means that you can have any length content between the two - it just simply updates the value when the `#header` classes are toggled.

I updated the snippet: removed the values that set the height of the containers from the CSS - now they stretch with the content.

Also, added a function to get the current `offsetTop` of an element - otherwise the values would be recalculated only on page refresh and not on if the window width (thus the container widths) changes.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  cacherHeader()
};

function getOffsetTop(el) {
  return el.offsetTop
}

const header = document.getElementById("header");
const essai = document.getElementById("essai");

function cacherHeader() {
  if (window.pageYOffset <= getOffsetTop(essai)) {
    if (header.classList.contains("afficher") == false) {
      header.classList.remove("cacher");
      header.classList.add("afficher");
    }
  } else {
    if (header.classList.contains("afficher") == true) {
      header.classList.remove("afficher");
      header.classList.add("cacher");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.fixe {
  position: fixed;
}

.afficher {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 2000ms ease, visibility 2000ms ease;
}

.cacher {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 2000ms ease, visibility 2000ms ease;
}

#header {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

#conteneur_01 {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#essai {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="fixe afficher">header</div>
<div id="conteneur_01">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam malesuada vulputate turpis, at dictum arcu pretium sit amet. Nunc mauris felis, fermentum luctus metus ac, tincidunt imperdiet dolor. Morbi neque odio, iaculis auctor fringilla finibus, dignissim
  bibendum ante. Sed faucibus sit amet ante non cursus. Nullam sit amet risus eros. Etiam imperdiet dictum orci vel ullamcorper. Sed eleifend magna in erat tincidunt, sed pharetra felis ullamcorper. Aenean eget velit nec augue ultricies varius ac sit
  amet lorem. Suspendisse eleifend aliquet dui, a mattis enim facilisis quis. Fusce pellentesque pretium nibh eu lacinia. Duis blandit ligula ac nibh ornare facilisis. Nullam tincidunt velit nec laoreet venenatis. Suspendisse quis dictum mi, sed venenatis
  ex. Donec eget leo et eros sagittis aliquet. Proin tristique, dui eget mollis scelerisque, justo sem placerat nisi, quis lobortis diam dui vel nunc. Curabitur lacinia eros a commodo ultricies. Donec ullamcorper at enim vel volutpat. Curabitur tristique
  lacinia interdum. Integer quis lobortis erat, vitae fermentum ligula. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pulvinar eleifend erat eu condimentum. Quisque cursus mi vitae malesuada mollis.
  Phasellus vel ullamcorper felis. Aliquam interdum ac orci in porttitor. Ut eu erat quis neque elementum bibendum. In rhoncus sed metus vitae dignissim. Sed ac volutpat lorem, eget molestie leo. Donec interdum mauris nibh, a dapibus mi fermentum eu.
  Maecenas tincidunt augue sem, vel imperdiet ante iaculis at. Morbi vulputate cursus risus sit amet ultrices. Aliquam quis ultricies massa. Pellentesque ac lectus vitae mi aliquet porta pretium sit amet enim. Integer porta lacus cursus vestibulum malesuada.
  Etiam pellentesque lorem sit amet nunc tristique cursus. Etiam ac ligula enim. Duis turpis orci, pulvinar quis sapien vel, sagittis aliquet nulla. Curabitur fermentum lectus non tortor ornare, ac iaculis risus porta. Quisque eu porttitor massa, vitae
  dictum velit. Etiam egestas tempor sem vel congue. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent sed massa viverra, dictum velit sit amet, vestibulum risus. Quisque sodales in tellus vel eleifend. Vivamus tempus blandit erat quis condimentum. Donec laoreet neque
  in pellentesque finibus. Morbi libero orci, finibus accumsan mollis id, bibendum quis mauris. Integer euismod et sapien in faucibus. Aenean efficitur ipsum quis lacus auctor auctor. Cras ut hendrerit eros. Curabitur nisl est, interdum et facilisis quis,
  varius ut lectus. Proin dignissim, ipsum et posuere ornare, arcu ipsum vehicula diam, eu rutrum lacus odio sed quam. Donec odio mi, varius nec condimentum vitae, auctor et arcu. Cras in aliquet erat, eget placerat ante. Mauris justo odio, mollis eu
  viverra eget, commodo id eros. Ut elit ipsum, cursus a ligula tincidunt, vulputate laoreet risus. Nulla aliquam viverra nulla sed ullamcorper. Aliquam id consequat quam. Curabitur ipsum lectus, finibus ac tortor sit amet, tristique dapibus lorem. Etiam
  rutrum nulla ac efficitur tincidunt. Nam non elit sapien. Etiam rutrum felis sed justo vehicula dictum. Vivamus in ipsum varius metus finibus cursus vel quis dolor. Fusce non malesuada ipsum. Donec gravida, ligula at eleifend commodo, tortor tellus
  eleifend orci, eget sodales neque quam nec elit. Ut sit amet finibus ex. Praesent ullamcorper dui at dui vestibulum, nec tincidunt libero vulputate. Phasellus tincidunt felis risus, et gravida nisi luctus nec. Mauris tristique faucibus justo, commodo
  pellentesque ipsum aliquet eu. Vivamus suscipit, leo quis sollicitudin convallis, dolor leo ultricies risus, nec maximus lacus ligula convallis velit. Nulla nibh magna, mollis non dapibus volutpat, vestibulum et mi. Ut pharetra nisi a purus aliquet,
  sed rutrum est sollicitudin. Nullam et sollicitudin nisi. Fusce interdum convallis convallis. Duis nisl dolor, finibus accumsan ex auctor, euismod mollis orci. Donec quis urna non mi maximus finibus. Vivamus luctus eros nec nulla varius, eget semper
  turpis ultricies. Fusce volutpat nulla nec ante fringilla, vel lacinia arcu tempor. Integer iaculis est eu feugiat ullamcorper. Vestibulum posuere nec leo at porta. Curabitur id congue neque. Quisque sapien quam, facilisis in auctor vitae, faucibus
  ac metus. Maecenas arcu nulla, fermentum non malesuada ut, vehicula vitae felis. Nunc consectetur, ante ut vulputate gravida, enim turpis sollicitudin dui, at tincidunt eros purus non dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut
  urna neque, tristique ut suscipit non, convallis quis orci. Vestibulum non lorem vel neque luctus mollis vitae eu quam. Nullam laoreet dignissim ex, vel fermentum dui cursus sit amet. Nullam vitae purus id orci ornare facilisis. Orci varius natoque
  penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer interdum nisi sit amet lorem auctor pharetra. Nunc sit amet sem mauris. Vestibulum venenatis eleifend odio, in porta quam fermentum non. Maecenas varius bibendum diam sed molestie.
  Praesent dapibus nibh eget consequat gravida. Nam pellentesque ipsum quis nunc efficitur, ac fermentum turpis cursus. Mauris tempus risus ac tellus ultricies tincidunt. Fusce sagittis eget nisi at dapibus. Integer eget posuere erat, quis pretium dui.
  Sed vel augue ut nisl mattis pretium a vel justo. Nunc consequat magna congue risus accumsan, eget consequat justo scelerisque. Maecenas dapibus purus id enim varius fringilla vel nec elit. Cras porttitor convallis nulla id ullamcorper. Donec hendrerit
  et augue sed facilisis. Fusce urna tortor, iaculis ut volutpat at, consequat vitae velit. Pellentesque volutpat pulvinar ultricies. Mauris lacinia, dui facilisis mattis elementum, sapien metus facilisis mi, vitae cursus justo magna eu nibh. Praesent
  rutrum egestas est ac blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur venenatis non dolor id condimentum. In dui ex, molestie vel bibendum sit amet, iaculis sit amet elit. Suspendisse interdum non erat sed scelerisque. Duis quis posuere elit. Quisque
  sodales cursus odio vitae efficitur. Vestibulum ultricies mollis urna, eget pharetra orci auctor ut. Aenean vel neque ac magna dapibus lacinia. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla facilisi. In commodo diam nisl, ac sollicitudin urna cursus a. Ut vehicula facilisis
  vulputate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin condimentum placerat enim sed viverra. Ut sed elementum diam, ut dapibus nunc. In ullamcorper laoreet ligula ut placerat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
  et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ultrices pulvinar elit et faucibus. Vivamus in porta quam. Donec iaculis lorem quis ipsum pharetra blandit. Maecenas scelerisque posuere elit, in malesuada sem vestibulum et. Etiam ultrices enim erat, non
  accumsan libero sagittis ac. Duis ornare nulla dolor, ac aliquet quam blandit at. Donec nec risus quis nulla dictum auctor. Pellentesque mauris est, viverra a felis ut, laoreet laoreet lectus. Aenean sit amet hendrerit eros. Suspendisse potenti. Donec
  in arcu scelerisque, scelerisque dui vitae, venenatis nulla. Fusce fermentum dui quis sapien efficitur, at tristique massa placerat. Curabitur vitae viverra nibh. Sed aliquet lacus eu orci accumsan, quis bibendum mi volutpat. In eu ante ullamcorper,
  iaculis turpis quis, imperdiet magna. Phasellus ornare facilisis quam, a tempor nulla viverra quis. In dui erat, venenatis eget justo gravida, lobortis imperdiet nisl. Ut faucibus eleifend ultricies. Proin malesuada enim ut tempus sagittis. Donec ac
  auctor lorem. Donec sed molestie lorem. Fusce scelerisque hendrerit sollicitudin. Duis maximus est vel dolor varius congue. Quisque mi ex, aliquet vitae ligula id, sagittis ornare elit. Pellentesque id aliquam neque.</div>
<div id="essai">Essai</div>
<div id="conteneur_02">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam malesuada vulputate turpis, at dictum arcu pretium sit amet. Nunc mauris felis, fermentum luctus metus ac, tincidunt imperdiet dolor. Morbi neque odio, iaculis auctor fringilla finibus, dignissim
  bibendum ante. Sed faucibus sit amet ante non cursus. Nullam sit amet risus eros. Etiam imperdiet dictum orci vel ullamcorper. Sed eleifend magna in erat tincidunt, sed pharetra felis ullamcorper. Aenean eget velit nec augue ultricies varius ac sit
  amet lorem. Suspendisse eleifend aliquet dui, a mattis enim facilisis quis. Fusce pellentesque pretium nibh eu lacinia. Duis blandit ligula ac nibh ornare facilisis. Nullam tincidunt velit nec laoreet venenatis. Suspendisse quis dictum mi, sed venenatis
  ex. Donec eget leo et eros sagittis aliquet. Proin tristique, dui eget mollis scelerisque, justo sem placerat nisi, quis lobortis diam dui vel nunc. Curabitur lacinia eros a commodo ultricies. Donec ullamcorper at enim vel volutpat. Curabitur tristique
  lacinia interdum. Integer quis lobortis erat, vitae fermentum ligula. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pulvinar eleifend erat eu condimentum. Quisque cursus mi vitae malesuada mollis.
  Phasellus vel ullamcorper felis. Aliquam interdum ac orci in porttitor. Ut eu erat quis neque elementum bibendum. In rhoncus sed metus vitae dignissim. Sed ac volutpat lorem, eget molestie leo. Donec interdum mauris nibh, a dapibus mi fermentum eu.
  Maecenas tincidunt augue sem, vel imperdiet ante iaculis at. Morbi vulputate cursus risus sit amet ultrices. Aliquam quis ultricies massa. Pellentesque ac lectus vitae mi aliquet porta pretium sit amet enim. Integer porta lacus cursus vestibulum malesuada.
  Etiam pellentesque lorem sit amet nunc tristique cursus. Etiam ac ligula enim. Duis turpis orci, pulvinar quis sapien vel, sagittis aliquet nulla. Curabitur fermentum lectus non tortor ornare, ac iaculis risus porta. Quisque eu porttitor massa, vitae
  dictum velit. Etiam egestas tempor sem vel congue. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent sed massa viverra, dictum velit sit amet, vestibulum risus. Quisque sodales in tellus vel eleifend. Vivamus tempus blandit erat quis condimentum. Donec laoreet neque
  in pellentesque finibus. Morbi libero orci, finibus accumsan mollis id, bibendum quis mauris. Integer euismod et sapien in faucibus. Aenean efficitur ipsum quis lacus auctor auctor. Cras ut hendrerit eros. Curabitur nisl est, interdum et facilisis quis,
  varius ut lectus. Proin dignissim, ipsum et posuere ornare, arcu ipsum vehicula diam, eu rutrum lacus odio sed quam. Donec odio mi, varius nec condimentum vitae, auctor et arcu. Cras in aliquet erat, eget placerat ante. Mauris justo odio, mollis eu
  viverra eget, commodo id eros. Ut elit ipsum, cursus a ligula tincidunt, vulputate laoreet risus. Nulla aliquam viverra nulla sed ullamcorper. Aliquam id consequat quam. Curabitur ipsum lectus, finibus ac tortor sit amet, tristique dapibus lorem. Etiam
  rutrum nulla ac efficitur tincidunt. Nam non elit sapien. Etiam rutrum felis sed justo vehicula dictum. Vivamus in ipsum varius metus finibus cursus vel quis dolor. Fusce non malesuada ipsum. Donec gravida, ligula at eleifend commodo, tortor tellus
  eleifend orci, eget sodales neque quam nec elit. Ut sit amet finibus ex. Praesent ullamcorper dui at dui vestibulum, nec tincidunt libero vulputate. Phasellus tincidunt felis risus, et gravida nisi luctus nec. Mauris tristique faucibus justo, commodo
  pellentesque ipsum aliquet eu. Vivamus suscipit, leo quis sollicitudin convallis, dolor leo ultricies risus, nec maximus lacus ligula convallis velit. Nulla nibh magna, mollis non dapibus volutpat, vestibulum et mi. Ut pharetra nisi a purus aliquet,
  sed rutrum est sollicitudin. Nullam et sollicitudin nisi. Fusce interdum convallis convallis. Duis nisl dolor, finibus accumsan ex auctor, euismod mollis orci. Donec quis urna non mi maximus finibus. Vivamus luctus eros nec nulla varius, eget semper
  turpis ultricies. Fusce volutpat nulla nec ante fringilla, vel lacinia arcu tempor. Integer iaculis est eu feugiat ullamcorper. Vestibulum posuere nec leo at porta. Curabitur id congue neque. Quisque sapien quam, facilisis in auctor vitae, faucibus
  ac metus. Maecenas arcu nulla, fermentum non malesuada ut, vehicula vitae felis. Nunc consectetur, ante ut vulputate gravida, enim turpis sollicitudin dui, at tincidunt eros purus non dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut
  urna neque, tristique ut suscipit non, convallis quis orci. Vestibulum non lorem vel neque luctus mollis vitae eu quam. Nullam laoreet dignissim ex, vel fermentum dui cursus sit amet. Nullam vitae purus id orci ornare facilisis. Orci varius natoque
  penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer interdum nisi sit amet lorem auctor pharetra. Nunc sit amet sem mauris. Vestibulum venenatis eleifend odio, in porta quam fermentum non. Maecenas varius bibendum diam sed molestie.
  Praesent dapibus nibh eget consequat gravida. Nam pellentesque ipsum quis nunc efficitur, ac fermentum turpis cursus. Mauris tempus risus ac tellus ultricies tincidunt. Fusce sagittis eget nisi at dapibus. Integer eget posuere erat, quis pretium dui.
  Sed vel augue ut nisl mattis pretium a vel justo. Nunc consequat magna congue risus accumsan, eget consequat justo scelerisque. Maecenas dapibus purus id enim varius fringilla vel nec elit. Cras porttitor convallis nulla id ullamcorper. Donec hendrerit
  et augue sed facilisis. Fusce urna tortor, iaculis ut volutpat at, consequat vitae velit. Pellentesque volutpat pulvinar ultricies. Mauris lacinia, dui facilisis mattis elementum, sapien metus facilisis mi, vitae cursus justo magna eu nibh. Praesent
  rutrum egestas est ac blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur venenatis non dolor id condimentum. In dui ex, molestie vel bibendum sit amet, iaculis sit amet elit. Suspendisse interdum non erat sed scelerisque. Duis quis posuere elit. Quisque
  sodales cursus odio vitae efficitur. Vestibulum ultricies mollis urna, eget pharetra orci auctor ut. Aenean vel neque ac magna dapibus lacinia. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla facilisi. In commodo diam nisl, ac sollicitudin urna cursus a. Ut vehicula facilisis
  vulputate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin condimentum placerat enim sed viverra. Ut sed elementum diam, ut dapibus nunc. In ullamcorper laoreet ligula ut placerat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
  et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ultrices pulvinar elit et faucibus. Vivamus in porta quam. Donec iaculis lorem quis ipsum pharetra blandit. Maecenas scelerisque posuere elit, in malesuada sem vestibulum et. Etiam ultrices enim erat, non
  accumsan libero sagittis ac. Duis ornare nulla dolor, ac aliquet quam blandit at. Donec nec risus quis nulla dictum auctor. Pellentesque mauris est, viverra a felis ut, laoreet laoreet lectus. Aenean sit amet hendrerit eros. Suspendisse potenti. Donec
  in arcu scelerisque, scelerisque dui vitae, venenatis nulla. Fusce fermentum dui quis sapien efficitur, at tristique massa placerat. Curabitur vitae viverra nibh. Sed aliquet lacus eu orci accumsan, quis bibendum mi volutpat. In eu ante ullamcorper,
  iaculis turpis quis, imperdiet magna. Phasellus ornare facilisis quam, a tempor nulla viverra quis. In dui erat, venenatis eget justo gravida, lobortis imperdiet nisl. Ut faucibus eleifend ultricies. Proin malesuada enim ut tempus sagittis. Donec ac
  auctor lorem. Donec sed molestie lorem. Fusce scelerisque hendrerit sollicitudin. Duis maximus est vel dolor varius congue. Quisque mi ex, aliquet vitae ligula id, sagittis ornare elit. Pellentesque id aliquam neque.</div>
```